# Why do the iOS main.m templates include a return statement and an autorelease pool?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I was re-reading `UIApplicationMain` documentation and wondered, if `UIApplicationMain` never returns, why:

- is there a `return` at the end?
- is there an `NSAutoreleasePool`?

I even ask myself: why `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` on an iPhone? 
Can we launch apps with a command line? What are `argc` and `argv` for? Are they used or just legacy C?

Some comments on Twitter from honorable fellows are that:

- `return` is here for the compiler
- the `NSAutoreleasePool` is useless.
- the run loop needs an autorelease pool to be allocated (contradicts #2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The return statement is probably just there because the compiler doesn't know that the function can never return (it is not marked up in any special way, after all). So the compiler's code flow analysis would warn that it had a missing return statement. That still doesn't explain why UIApplicationMain() has a return value, though. Maybe there is an error situation where it actually *can* return, who knows.

2) I think having an autorelease pool in main() *around UIApplicationMain* is wrong, as any object released without a pool will end up in this autorelease pool, which persists for the entire duration of the application. So effectively the object is still leaked.

Usually, if there is no autorelease pool in place, the runtime logs an error message about the missing pool and tells the developer to set a breakpoint on _NSAutoreleaseNoPool to find where the pool-less autorelease happens. The top-level NSAutoreleasePool as found in the templates thus actually *hides* this leak from the users.

UIApplicationMain() should build its own autorelease pool as needed (It has to create and tear down a pool once through the event loop anyway, otherwise objects would just add up in the outer pool, consuming all memory). If someone thinks they really need to run ObjC code before calling UIApplicationMain() (and they can't do the same work in applicationDidFinishLaunching: or the likes), they can always create a pool *before* UIApplicationMain(). Since UIApplicationMain() is documented to never return (like exit()), there is no point in having commands following it anyway. The pool would never get released.

If you look at the Mac templates, they actually do not have the pool.

3) The parameters are used even if you double-click an application on the Mac. The OS passes certain information to the application that way. The first parameter is the path to the executable when it was launched, which is necessary to find files in the bundle, I presume. On the Mac, the PSN (process serial number) is also passed to an application as a parameter when launched from the Finder:

```
05.07.11 22:18:54,129 [0x0-0x21e21e].com.thevoidsoftware.MacTestApp: 0: /Volumes/RamDisk/MacTestApp-fdcuwfrzopalmgaufwujijhqhvjc/Build/Products/Debug/MacTestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MacTestApp
05.07.11 22:18:54,129 [0x0-0x21e21e].com.thevoidsoftware.MacTestApp: 1: -psn_0_2220574
```

Comment: Regarding the Mac templates, maybe it is because they use garbage collection (not reference-counted environment)? on iOS, we don't have it.

Comment: @Cyril Godefroy only lazy developers use garbage collection and it's not enabled by default. I hate it, but that's my opinion.

Comment: You can answer that question for yourself if you have access to pre-release software. I can't say more.

Answer (score 0):

On the arguments part, on iOS, if you launch directly the app you only get one argument, the app path

```
2011-07-05 22:38:15.004 iCyril[2326:707] There are 1 args
Argument 1 : /var/mobile/Applications/7D58CC99-89C3-4F86-93D9-5FAF0756B706/iCyril.app/iCyril
```

Given that you can open files, read urls etc from the UIApplication delegate methods, the other info must be handled by the same mechanism.

Comment: Unlikely. That would make it impossible to open a document or URL with an application that is already running. On MacOS, Apple Events are used to tell an application to open a file/URL. Those in turn are based on Mach messages under the hood these days. I presume iOS has something equivalent, internally.